# Android and setting alpha for (image) view alpha

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview, alpha

Is there really no XML attribute counterpart to `setAlpha(int)`?

If not, what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

No, there is not, see how the "Related XML Attributes" section is *missing* in the [ImageView.setAlpha(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) documentation. The alternative is to use [View.setAlpha(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) whose [XML counterpart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha) is `android:alpha`. It takes a range of 0.0 to 1.0 instead of 0 to 255. Use it e.g. like

```
<ImageView android:alpha="0.4">
```

However, the latter in available only since API level 11.

Comment: Even if I'm just repeating myself here: `ImageView.setAlpha(int)` is taking an `int` while `android:alpha` is taking a float, so strictly speaking the latter is not the exact XML counterpart to the former, but it's the counterpart to `View.setAlpha(float)`. And as mentioned multiple times here already, `android:alpha` / `View.setAlpha(float)` are available as of API level 11 only.

Comment: the difference is that the acceptable range is 0-1 for the float one and 0-255 for the int one.

Answer (score 258):

It's easier than the other response.
There is an xml value `alpha` that takes double values.

`android:alpha="0.0"`  thats invisible

`android:alpha="0.5"`  see-through

`android:alpha="1.0"`  full visible

That's how it works.

Comment: There is `setAlpha(float)` and `android:alpha` only since API 11 (Android 3.0). Prior API 11 one must use code to set alpha for image. As sschuberth already said in anser above.

Comment: @Antonio Why? This answer does not add any information on top of mine, and on the contrary is less complete.

Comment: @sschuberth your answer is completely correct, but the lack of an example could make this answer take more attention than yours. Although your answer provides more information, this answer provides a solution closer to what I really need. Please, add some examples to use what you have explained, that absolutely will help!

Answer (score 56):

I am not sure about the XML but you can do it by code in the following way.

```
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);
myImageView.setAlpha(xxx);
```

In pre-API 11:

- range is from 0 to 255 (inclusive), 0 being transparent and 255 being opaque.

In API 11+:

- range is from 0f to 1f (inclusive), 0f being transparent and 1f being opaque.

Comment: Yep, I know. (I hoped this was implicit in the question.) One point of XML is to strip out some of this code. It doesn't make sense to me why `alpha` does not have an XML-attribute counterpart when various sizes, positions do.

Comment: i wonder : why is it deprecated? is it because now they have a float parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can use imageView.setAlpha(1.0f), but requires API level 11.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a helpful alternative for a **plain-colored** background:

Put a *LinearLayout* over the *ImageView* and use the *LinearLayout* as a opacity filter. In the following a small example with a black background:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF000000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_stop_big" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/opacityFilter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Vary the *android:background* attribute of the *LinearLayout* between *#00000000* (fully transparent) and *#FF000000* (fully opaque).

Comment: Not really the best of doing it to solve the alpha of an image problem especially on the phone device.

Comment: This works great when you just want to make background transparent but NOT its childs. Using alpha on the parent container, makes all its childs transparent too

Answer (score 9):

There is now an XML alternative:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        android:alpha="0.7" />
```

It is: **android:alpha="0.7"**

With a value from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque).

Answer (score 6):

`setAlpha(int)` is deprecated as of API `16`: `Android 4.1`

Please use `setImageAlpha(int)` instead

Answer (score 4):

use android:alpha=0.5 to achieve the opacity of 50% and to turn Android Material icons from Black to Grey.

Answer (score 3):

Use this form to ancient version of android.

```
ImageView myImageView;
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.5F, 0.5F);
alpha.setDuration(0); 
alpha.setFillAfter(true); 
myImageView.startAnimation(alpha);
```

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the opacity of anything in XML Android, use the Attribute Alpha.
Example:

```
android:alpha="0.6"
```

You must enter the value between range of 0.0 to 1.0, in points.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha can be set along with the color using the following hex format #ARGB or #AARRGGBB.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: I want to set the alpha of an image using an XML attribute. Does this help?

Comment: I am using to this to bleand layouts over a layout with a background image, surely you would set the the alpha of an image in the image itself?

Comment: What do you mean "in the image itself"? Within the XML? An oversight it may be, but there's no alpha XML attribute.

Comment: I mean when you create the image you would add a transparency layer and set the opacity of your image to 50 or whatever value you require.

Comment: I am VERY surprised that android:tint has no effect. It allows for an alpha value... but it has not effect on a white image :-(((((