# image.setAlpha on Android lollipop not work

Tags: android, opacity

After testing my app on Android 5.0, I noticed that image.setAlpha() is not working on this Android version.

I tried with image.setImagealpha() function, but it returns this error:
"The method setImageAlpha(int) is undefined for the type Drawable"

The API level that I´m using on my app is 8

What can I do?

Comment: ImageView has the method setAlpha(float) after API 11. Before API 11 it uses setAlpha(int). Are you giving it a float value instead of an int? For 80% transparency you would do imageView.setAlpha(0.8);

Comment: I am giving an int value.
I want the app to work both API 8 and Android 5.0

Comment: I have posted a solution that should work. Please mark it as the correct answer if it did resolve your issue. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2019:**

With **kotlin** now we can do it like this:

```
imageView.post {imageView.alpha = 1.0f}
```

I have used  `View.post` so that it get updated on immediate next UI updation cycle.

Without posting on UI thread sometimes setting alpha of TextViews doesn't reflect on UI as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do)

Answer (score 1):

ImageView has the method setAlpha(float) after API 11. Before API 11 it uses setAlpha(int). Since you want to support API 8 and above, you have to specify the different states. So to resolve this, use the following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    //For API 11 and above use a float such as 0.54.(54% transparency)        
    imageView.setAlpha(float);
}
else
    //For API Below 11 use an int such as 54.
    imageView.setAlpha(int);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for doing that code, but it didn´t work :s

Comment: I did some more researching around and found this. See if this works and incorporate it with my code for checking the API level. Good Luck! http://stackoverflow.com/a/4931349/1371041