# Alpha attribute only work on Android Lollipop, why?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-bitmap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
    android:alpha="0.4"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</bitmap>
```

This piece of code works well only on android API 21 (lollipop).

Are there any ways to set alpha for drawables in previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for a bitmap you could apply the `android:alpha` property to the `ImageView` which is containing this picture and it'll mechanically set the alpha to the wanted picture.

To do that refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16417259/2545832) and it'll look like this:

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```