# How to create a transparent radial pie menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an ui similar to the following.
but the problem is that the ui is not very much transparent. Is there any other alternative to get an ui like the following?
You can find the code that I tried [github](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)

[image: iM]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to look at setting the Alpha component(s).

This link may be of use:- [Android and setting alpha for (image) view alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha)