# How to set a default icons color and other attributes

Tags: android, material-design

I want to change the default color for icons on Android Studio and set alpha to 60%.

How can I do this on `styles.xml` file?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please kindly take your time to read and learn: How To Ask Question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

For changing color use:

```
android:tint="@android:color/white"
```

For setting alpha to 60%, change this

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

to

```
 <color name="white">#99ffffff</color> <!-- 99 is for 60% alpha and other pairs are for R G B -->
```

Check these:

- [Android and setting alpha for (image) view alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha)
- [How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android#7689776)
- [How to make a background 20% transparent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android)

I cann't comment because of low points